# How to structure an Eclipse Java project with modules and test dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-platform-module-system

I am struggling to setup my java project in Eclipse. My Project has the following properties

- Its a maven project
- It is modularized (module-info.java)
- It contains unit tests

The project structure looks like this:

```
MyProject
|- src/main/java
|  |- (All the packages)
|  |- module-info.java
|- src/test/java
|  |- (All test packages)
|- pom.xml
```

So the problem i am having is that the test dependencies are only visible for my test when i include them in module-info.jar

```
module MyProject {
    exports dev.dietermai.MyProject;

    requires org.junit.jupiter.api;
}
```

But i can not include the test dependencies in module-info.jar because the test dependencies have the scope "test" and are therefore not visibel in the src/main/java.

I think the root of the issue is that eclipse things the the test source in src/test/java are part of the module in src/main/java.

I tried the following solution

- Move module-info.java to src/test/java: This does not work because now eclipse things the project is modular, but all dependencies defined in module-info.java are no longer visible (since its in the test folder)
- Add a second module-info.java to src/test/java: This causes a lot of errors in eclipse (Error log messages/Error popus/Broken PackageExplorer)
- Create a second project only for the test: This works but i loos the default maven directory structure.
- Remove the test-flag from the src/test/java directory in eclipse: This works, but now the eclipse settings and maven settings are out of sync and are reverted whenever it gets synced.

So at this point I think I'm just doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: `But i can not include the test dependencies in module-info.jar because the test dependencies have the scope "test" and are therefore not visibel in the src/main/java.` In the module-info there should be no test dependencies becuse they will never be part of the production code... furthermore why would you like to put a `module-info.java` into `src/test/java` ? You are writing unit. tests? Or do you write integration tests?

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't want to but my test dependencies in module-info.java and i don't want to put module-info.java into src/test/java. These are just things i have tried as a workaround. The actual problem is that my test dependencies in src/test/java are not visible because they are not defined in the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there was nothing wrong with my project structure.
The actual issue is the the Eclipse maven plugin (m2e) gets out of sync with the eclipse project settings. Usually m2e realizes when it is out of sync and tells you that you should update the project again. But in this case it does not. Instead you get a bunch of other error that are only fixed once you sync again (Project -> Update Maven Project)